# Restoring a SQL Server 2012 database in high availability

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, restore, availability-groups

I have a database which is in always-on high availability mode synchronized with another database on a different instance. How can I restore from a `.bak` file into the primary database using `T-SQL`?

I'm new to high availability and I've been advised that I need to take the database out of high availability before I can do a restore and then put it back in high availability again but I'm not sure.

I'm hoping I can just restore straight into the primary while the `AlwaysOn` is still enabled and it will auto sync with the secondary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Listen to your adviser.  By restoring a backup, you are essentially replacing the database schema and data.  You will need to turn synchronization off, remove the DB from HA and perform the restore on the primary and replica, leaving the replica version in a restoring state by using WITH NORECOVERY.  Once your backup is in place, put the DB back into HA and start synchronization again.

HA is very similar to mirroring and uses similar technology, just not nearly as finicky.  You will want to treat your HA DBs similarly as well.

Code would be similar to the following:

--on primary

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP MyAG REMOVE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012;
```

--on primary

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups
   WITH NORECOVERY, 
      MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Data' TO 
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.mdf', 
      MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Log' 
TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.

RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks2012
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups
   WITH RECOVERY;
```

--on secondary

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups
   WITH NORECOVERY, 
      MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Data' TO 
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.mdf', 
      MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Log' 
TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.ldf';

RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks2012
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups
   WITH NORECOVERY;
```

--on primary

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP MyAG ADD DATABASE AdventureWorks2012;
```

--on secondary

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 SET HADR AVAILABILITY GROUP = MyAG;
```

Comment: Question regarding the answer above ... In the code supplied, the PRIMARY was restored with NoRecovery. It was my thought that only the Replica would be done with NoRecovery.

Comment: Correct, but keep reading. Log restores were coded and then finally WITH RECOVERY to make it available for use.

Comment: If one is unable to rejoin the availability group on the secondary, then restoring a transaction log may be needed. [This source](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22594415/Mirrorring-failed-to-start-from-management-studio.html) helped resolve the following error: `The mirror database, "dbname", has insufficient transaction log data to preserve the log backup chain of the principal database.  
This may happen if a log backup from the principal database has not been taken or has not been restored on the mirror database.`

Comment: Hence the log restores.  See comment above.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli thank you for putting this up. It has come in handy. I understand now you are restoring from a logical backup device instead of from file. When I restore from file I use separate .bak and .trn files.

Comment: @HansVonn, correct.  Restore from whatever medium you are using.