# Sync while Restore Operation

Tags: sql-server-2014, availability-groups, data-synchronization

I am trying to restore the Latest content to one of my Primary Replica Database which is part of AOAG.

My question is during the Restore operation,

1) Will the synchronization still happens between Application and DB server ?

2) During the DB restoration will the DB which is part of AOAG is locked out so that the synchronization with Secondary AOAG replica not happens ?

Comment: Can you please clarify more

Comment: @TheGameiswar ,hi please let me know if my questions is still confusing I just edited.

Comment: ` DB restoration` are we talking about restore on primary

Comment: Yes @TheGameiswar,sorry just now updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Will the synchronization still happens between Application and DB server ?

No synchronization will not happen during restore operation

> During the DB restoration will the DB which is part of AOAG is locked out so that the synchronization with Secondary AOAG replica not happens ?

Please note that you cannot just go ahead and restore database which is part of availability group, you would have to evict database from AOAG, restore it and then add it back to AOAG see [This Link](https://michaelfirsov.wordpress.com/sql-2014-restoring-a-database-that-is-part-of-an-alwayson-availability-group/). The query would look like below(shamelessly copied from [This SE thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82548/restoring-a-sql-server-2012-database-in-high-availability))

--on primary

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP MyAG REMOVE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012;
```

--on primary

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups
   WITH NORECOVERY, 
      MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Data' TO 
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.mdf', 
      MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Log' 
TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.ldf';
RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks2012
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups
   WITH RECOVERY;
```

--on secondary

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups
   WITH NORECOVERY, 
      MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Data' TO 
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.mdf', 
      MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Log' 
TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.ldf';
RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks2012
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups
   WITH NORECOVERY;
```

--on primary

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP MyAG ADD DATABASE AdventureWorks2012;
```

--on secondary

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 SET HADR AVAILABILITY GROUP = MyAG;
```

Comment: Shanky,thanks much I missed this point evict database from AOAG.

Comment: Shanky ,if I am using GUI I can follow this method : First Restore the database with recovery and then navigate to Availability Databases and select Add Database ... and so on , is this ok ?

Comment: Follow the first link I have added in my answer, it shows how to remove, restore and re add the database in AOAG